# CSS Anchor tag won't inherit display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to get my anchor tag to `display: inherit` but it will not change. I have also added `!important` but it will still not alter the display of the anchor tag. Here is my code:

```css
div.et_pb_blurb_container {
  background: white;
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
  width: 90%;
  margin: -80px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  line-height: 1.7em !important;
}

#blurbbutton {
  background: #151d3f;
  display: inherit !important;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100% !important;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

p { all: initial !important; }
```

```html
<div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
  <div class="et_pb_blurb_description">

    <h4>This is a great website</h4>
    <p><a id="blurbbutton" href="www.google.com">Click the link here</a></p>

  </div>
  <!-- .et_pb_blurb_description -->

</div>
```

If the anchor tag were to inherit the size of it's container then it would work. However, for some reason adding `display: inherit` to the CSS of `#blurbbutton` is not working.

Comment: What is the behavior that you expect and the one that you are getting? It seems to be working fine on the demo (it's getting the `display: block` from the `p` that contains it)

Comment: I expect the anchor tag to not overlap with the h4 and instead start underneath the h4 without white spaces on the side. Currently, the anchor tag is starting on top of the h4 tag and it is not stretching to the sides like the h4.

Comment: That's not the behavior that can be seen in the demo above. The `a` doesn't overlap de `h4`, and it stretches to occupy the available width in the parent container. Are you seeing this issue in any browser in particular?

Comment: On my server, I am using bootstrap and the anchor tag is not inheriting the full width of the h4 tag above in their container. Instead, the anchor tag is not inheriting and showing partially on top of the h4 tag's comment. If I set "overflow: hidden" it moves the anchor tag inside of the h4 tag's padding. I would like to do the opposite of "overflow: hidden" and have the anchor tag start right underneath the h4 tag's padding, with inherit display. However, it will not inherit the display.

Comment: I don't see the error that you are describing. When I execute the code on the question I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n28Ql.png): the anchor tag is inheriting the display:block from the p, it is stretching to the full width of the container (shifted some 15 pixels to the left because of the margin), and it doesn't overlap the h4.

Comment: I have found the issue. Initially, I set p {
  all: initial !important;
  } . This was affecting the anchor from inheriting correctly. Now, in my chrome developer tools, I am able to remove the "display: inherit" property and it takes effect. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. You should add it as an answer below (and if possible edit the question to add a bit more information, for example, the styling of the p should be there to understand the problem/solution).

Comment: Thank you Alvaro, I added your recommendations to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I set p { all: initial !important; } . This was affecting the anchor from inheriting correctly. Now, in my chrome developer tools, I am able to remove the "display: inherit" property and it takes effect.